# Could not able to fetch data in datasource in Tableau Desktop,Throws below error

Tags: tableau-api

> Unable to complete action
> [Hortonworks][HiveODBC] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while execurint query. Error message from server: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Argument type mismatch 'TOK_NULL': The expression after ELSE should have the same type as those after THEN: "date" is expected but "timestamp" is found
> Error Code: 9F80FB23

Answer (score 0):

It tells you what the problem is. check your query.

```
The expression after ELSE should have the same type as those after THEN: "date" is expected but "timestamp" is found
```